# adb.exe start server failed android studio

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

1. i type adb nodaemon server
   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one u
   sage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
2. netstat -ano | findstr 5037
   TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5652
   TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:55726        ESTABLISHED     5652
   TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:55770        ESTABLISHED     5652
   TCP    127.0.0.1:55726        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     1620
   TCP    127.0.0.1:55770        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     6488
   So i could not find any error .I dont knw wny showing adb.exe start server failed.So what to do  please help to resolve

Answer (score 33):

Are you using Genymotion? When using Genymotion, try setting the Genymotion config to use the same Android SDK that uses Android Studio.

Anyway, if you aren't using Genymotion, check if you are using two different SDK.

Be sure to set anything that uses Android SDK, to the same SDK path.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 26):

Another process is already listening to this port.

You should close him.

**Follow these steps:**

1. write the following command:

   netstat -ano | findstr 5037
2. Then take the PID
3. Find it in the taskmgr and close it.
4. Try to install again.

Comment: i dont knw how to find PID in taskmgr

Comment: on the taskmgr rightclick on the column "Name". Do "v" on PID. then you'll able to see the PID column

Answer (score 2):

Can change adb port and start.

```
adb -P 5038 start-server
```